# How to connect to postgresql database inside AWS EC2 instance using Node.js and Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I rented an EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.xx on AWS and installed PostgreSQL on it. I created a database and table inside the PostgreSQL on EC2. Right now I am trying to connect to and get data from the database via a local Node.js project using `knex`.

I already enabled the inbound rule for port 5432 to IP from anywhere.

However, it returns error message as below:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.229.xxx.xxx:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1142:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '13.229.xxx.xxx',
  port: 5432
}
```

How am I gonna fix it? Do I need to install and implement a reversed proxy? If so, how do I set it up? I know there is RDS on AWS, but I need to use EC2 to implement it.

Here are some of my codes:

This is the `knex` setting, I have pg installed. The connection to a local database is successful. But when I switch the host to whether a public IP/ private IP/ ec2-13-229-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com. They all return the above error message.

```
development: {
        client: 'postgresql',
        connection: {
            host: '13.229.xxx.xxx',
            database: 'project2',
            user: 'postgres',
            password: 'postgres',
            port: 5432,
        },
        pool: {
            min: 2,
            max: 10,
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations',
        },
    },
```

This is the Node.js code that I used to connect to the server. A very simple one, just to test the connection.

```
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const app = express();
const knexConfig = require('./knexfile')['development'];
const knex = require('knex')(knexConfig);

let query = knex.select('*').from('users');

query
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

[This is my firewall setting which is turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLheH.png)

Also, I paused my Kaspersky.

[This is my pg_hba.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AcMw.png)

And I am not sure where to add the permission of my personal IP.

Comment: Can you confirm you have enabled inbound access via the Postgres DBs security group?

Comment: Yes, I did. There are two 5432 ports are open to anywhere, one is ::/0, another is 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Any way you can include any more of your code? Can we rule out NACLs, and your internal office firewall. Finally can you confirm the contents of the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: @mokugo-devops sure! but how do I cinfirm the contents of pg_hba.conf, I command "cd", and nothing is shown

Comment: Take a look at https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003321434-How-to-enable-remote-access-to-PostgreSQL-server-on-a-Plesk-server-

Comment: Can you add your pg_hba.conf contents now? (Blur your IP)

Comment: "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "116.xx.xx.xx", user "postgres", database "project2", SSL on" Yes, I have this error now, I will add the setting code to my post now

Comment: I add the code "local all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" on each line and delete. And finally somehow got it to work! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem added answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was related to the `pg_hba.conf` being restricted to localhost only.

Additionally the postgres.conf needed to have `listen_addresses = '*'`.

By whitelisting outside access, it was possible to access the database.

Additional support from [this article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003321434-How-to-enable-remote-access-to-PostgreSQL-server-on-a-Plesk-server-).

Comment: Yes, especially the `listen_addresses = '*'` part where you can whitelist certain IP addresses/hostnames